# I want to add Map in innerHTML of Div(Dynamically created)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to add Map in innerHTML of Div(Dynamically created).....

```
var ni = document.getElementById('content');
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id',idname);
newdiv.innerHTML = map[i];//it is not adding map,because map[i] is not defined...how to solve this...
ni.appendChild(newdiv);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(idname),myOptions);
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here that is wrong.

Lines 1-3,5. You've made #newdiv and appended it to your content div. Great!

Line 4: You're trying to set the contents of your new div with something that doesn't exist. *Delete this line.*

Line 6-11: Stock Google Maps code, straight from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Line 13: (unlucky for some) This line would handle the insertion of Google Maps to your page, if you changed the idname variable. How about trying this:

```
map[i] = new google.maps.Map(ni, myOptions);
```

This will set up the Map object that you can use and put it in map[i]. Of course, I'm assuming you have a value for `i` and have initialised `map`. If not, then change `map[i] =` to `var map =`.

That should make your life easier :)